# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' in Deepspeech

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, mozilla-deepspeech

I am trying to decode a wav file after training a model from scratch, i finished the training and the testing phase without errors and I get the WER & CER and Loss values.
NB: I’ve already done the decoding with this command with no errors but it appeared when I tested with a new model.

```
native_client/deepspeech --model /home/xyz/DeepSpeech/data/exprt_dir/output_graph.pb --scorer /home/xyz/DeepSpeech/data/lm/lm.scorer --audio data/test5.wav --beam_width 9000 > data/decoding.txt
TensorFlow: v2.2.0-15-g518c1d0
DeepSpeech: v0.9.0-alpha.3-0-g78ae08c
Warning: reading entire model file into memory. Transform model file into an  mmapped graph to reduce heap usage.
2020-09-22 12:15:00.293543: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143]  Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
what():  vector::_M_default_append
Abandon (core dumped)`
```

I tried the command without the scorer, pipe and beam and with a file from the train dataset but the error still persists.

```
native_client/deepspeech --model /home/xyz/DeepSpeech/data/exprt_dir/output_graph.pb --audio data/decoding_online/test5.wav
TensorFlow: v2.2.0-15-g518c1d0
DeepSpeech: v0.9.0-alpha.3-0-g78ae08c
Warning: reading entire model file into memory. Transform model file into an mmapped graph to reduce heap usage.
2020-09-22 13:56:17.511266: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143]       Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
what():  vector::_M_default_append
Abandon (core dumped)
```

you find below the versions of packages i have (running pip list shows more than these packages but i just kept the important ones)

```
(deepspeech-venv) (base) root@xyz:/home/xyz/DeepSpeech# pip  list
Package              Version      Location                            
-------------------- ------------ ------------------------------------
deepspeech-training  0.9.0a3      /home/xyz/DeepSpeech/training
ds-ctcdecoder        0.9.0a3      
tensorboard          1.15.0       
tensorflow-estimator 1.15.1       
tensorflow-gpu       1.15.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, the problem is discussed in length on [Discourse](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/error-when-trying-to-decode-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-std-length-error/67967).

In general, don't use the master branch if you are not actively developing DeepSpeech as it sometimes breaks.